# Event key arrow in Java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyboard-events

I am simulating Superman flying in Java.

How can I make a event that considers both the right arrow and left arrow keys?

I set up the event of each arrow like so:

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
 int KeyCode=e.getKeyCode();

 switch(KeyCode)
 {
     case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
         supermanleft.moveLeft();
         break;
     case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
         supermanfly.moveRight();
         break;
     case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
         superman.moveUp();
         break;
     case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
         superman.moveDown();
         break;
 }
}
```

When I click the two arrows simultaneously, Superman goes back.

Comment: Should it go diagonal or not? If no, add a boolean flag.

Answer (score 0):

When both keys are pressed, each one will call `keyPressed`. You can maintain a set of keys pressed and then see if there are two keys pressed that you need:

```
private Set<Character> pressed = new HashSet<Character>();

public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    pressed.add(e.getKeyChar());

    if (pressed.size() > 1) {
        //check if pressed contains what you want it to contain
    } else {
       //only one key is pressed - act as normal
    }
}

public synchronized void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    //don't forget to remove when released:
    pressed.remove(e.getKeyChar());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What’s the point of adding `synchronized` to the methods? Besides that, `getKeyChar()` should be used for `KEY_TYPED` events only. When you want to track which keys are currently pressed, you should use `getKeyCode()` to query the actual *key* rather than *character*.